# A question concerning the triplet $V\subset H\subset V^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In Brezis' Functional Analysis book, p. 150, there is an exercise about the triplet $V\subset H\subset V^*$, where $(V,\|\cdot\|_{V})$ is a Banach space, $H$ is a Hilbert space with the scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)_{H}$ and associated norm $|\cdot|_{H}$. Further, $V$ is continuously injected and dense in $H$.

Considering the operator $T:H\rightarrow V^*$ defined by

$$\langle T u,v\rangle_{V^*,V}=(u, v)_{H}\;\;\forall u \in H,\;\;\forall v\in V,$$

I already showed the following properties: (1) $\|Tu\|_{V^*}\leq C|u|_H\;\;\forall u\in H$; (2) $T$ is injective; (3) The range of $T$, $R(T)$, is dense en $V^*$ if $V$ is reflexive.

However, there is another property, that I have problems with its proof.

According to Brezis, it is possible to show that given $f \in V^*$, we have the following property:

$f \in R(T)\Leftrightarrow$  $\exists\; a \geq 0$ such that $|\langle f, v\rangle_{V^*,V}|\leq a | v |_H$ $\forall \;v\in V$.

The implication $(\Rightarrow)$ is clearly obtained. And the implication $(\Leftarrow)$ is clear if $a=0$, because we take $f=T(0)=0$. But the case $a>0$, it has been a pain head. In some sense, if the inequality holds for every $v\in V$, the value of $|\langle f, v\rangle_{V^*,V}|$ is related with the scalar product in $H$ due to the presence of $|v|_H$ on the right hand side of the inequality, and this suggest that $f$ must be expressed in terms of $T$, because $T$ is defined by the scalar product in $H$.

But how can I ensure that there exists $u_f\in H$ (depending on $f$) such that $f=Tu_f$?

One idea was to try to prove that $|\langle f, v\rangle_{V^*,V}-\langle Tu, v\rangle_{V^*,V}|=0$ for some $u\in H$ and for all $v\in V$. However, I just attained the following inequalities:

$$0\leq|\langle f, v\rangle_{V^*,V}-\langle Tu, v\rangle_{V^*,V}|\leq (a+|u|_H)|v|_H.$$

In this point I don't know how to proceed.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: How you have to show that if V is reflexive then R(T) is dense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
We define $\varphi : V \to \mathbb R$ by
$\varphi(v) := \langle f,v\rangle_{V^*,V}$.
Now, we view $V$ as a (dense) subspace of $H$ and,
thus, the functional $\varphi$ is defined on this dense subspace
and continuous w.r.t. the norm in $H$.

Comment: You're right! Thanks to the Hahn-Banach theorem, it is possible to extend the functional $\varphi$ to the whole $H$ by continuity and then, by Riesz representation theorem, $\varphi\in H^*$ can be represented as the scalar product in $H$. This gives us the element $w\in H$ such that $f=Tw$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need Hahn-Banach: $\varphi$ is defined on a dense subspace, so it can be extended by continuity.

Comment: Yes, you are right!! Thanks a lot!!!